FFmpegKit in Flutter fails with configuration output on Android
I am using ffmpeg_kit_flutter in my Flutter app to add a text overlay to a video. However, when I try to execute the FFmpeg command, I get an output similar to this:
configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable...
Here is my code:
final command = '-i $_videoPath -vf "drawtext=text=\'Live Score: 10 - 5\':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=10:y=10" $_processedVideoPath';

await FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((session) async {
  final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
  final output = await session.getOutput();
  final errorOutput = await session.getFailStackTrace();

  print('Return Code: $returnCode');
  print('Output: $output');
  print('Error Output: $errorOutput');
});

Dependencies:
ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3
